# POST Request in Jupyter notebook

Tags: api, python-requests, request, http-post

i want to get id token from my credentials, i have an url, header, and body from client:

i do code in jupyter like this but did not work, any idea?

```
import requests
import json
import os

url = "https://xxxxx"

querystring = {"page":"0","limit":"50","sort":"desc"}

payload = "{'key':'value'}"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json"
    }
body = {
    'email': "{{email}}",
    'password': "{{password}}"
    }
resp = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, body=body)
respText = json.loads(resp.text)
respText['data']
```

Comment: you can delete payload, and request("post", url, json=body, headers=headers) that work for me. You have to specify json=your data !